# Only the last Cell gets added to the Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to manually add three headers to a table.  The table fills out fine with data from the SqlDataReader, but I'm having trouble getting the first row to stick.

```
        TableRow iRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell iCell = new TableCell();
        iCell.Text = "SUBMITTED BY";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
        iCell.Text = "ON";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
        iCell.Text = "ISSUE DESCRIPTION";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
        table.Rows.Add(iRow);
```

causes only the last entry, in this case, ISSUE DESCRIPTION, to show up on the table.  I've found a workaround in

```
        TableRow iRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell iCell = new TableCell();
        TableCell iCell2 = new TableCell();
        TableCell iCell3 = new TableCell();
        iCell.Text = "SUBMITTED BY";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
        iCell2.Text = "ON";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell2);
        iCell3.Text = "ISSUE DESCRIPTION";
        iRow.Cells.Add(iCell3);
        table.Rows.Add(iRow);
```

but it's bothering me how much messier that is.  Is something wrong with my logic, or is there something I'm missing in C#?  I've got a pretty good handle on C, but just started C# a couple weeks ago.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> is there something I'm missing in C#

Sounds like it, yes.

This:

```
TableCell iCell = new TableCell();
```

creates a `TableCell` object, and assigns a *reference* to it to the `iCell` variable. The value of `iCell` is *just* a reference to the object. It's not the object itself. This:

```
iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
```

passes that *reference* to the `Add` method. It *doesn't* pass an object to `Add` - you can never do that in C#. So your row ends up with lots of references to the same cell, and all the changes you've made in lines like this:

```
iCell.Text = "ON";
```

just overwrite each other, as they're making changes to the same object.

You may find these articles useful:

- [References and values](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)
- [Parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)

Personally I would change your code to use collection initializers and object initializers:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow {
    Cells = {
        new TableCell { Text = "SUBMITTED BY" },
        new TableCell { Text = "ON" },
        new TableCell { Text = "ISSUE DESCRIPTION" },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to recreate `iCell` each time, otherwise you are re-adding the same instance over and over and just changing its text.  Since they are all the same instance, the `.Add(..)` operation recognizes this and doesn't add it again, so there is effectively still only one cell in the row at the end of the code - the single instance of `iCell`.

Here's an example that should work correctly:

```
TableRow iRow = new TableRow();
TableCell iCell = new TableCell();
iCell.Text = "SUBMITTED BY";
iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
iCell = new TableCell(); // create new cell
iCell.Text = "ON";
iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
iCell = new TableCell(); // create new cell
iCell.Text = "ISSUE DESCRIPTION";
iRow.Cells.Add(iCell);
table.Rows.Add(iRow);
```

If you want to make your code a little cleaner, you could create a helper method that returns a new cell instance with a parameter given for the text:

```
public TableCell CreateCell(string text) {
    TableCell iCell = new TableCell();
    iCell.Text = text;
    return iCell;
}
```

Then your code could be simplified to the following:

```
TableRow iRow = new TableRow();
iRow.Cells.Add(CreateCell("SUBMITTED BY"));
iRow.Cells.Add(CreateCell("ON"));
iRow.Cells.Add(CreateCell("ISSUE DESCRIPTION"));
table.Rows.Add(iRow);
```